# JavaScript Global Object referencing vs 'this'

Tags: javascript, reference, scope

I'm working on an application framework written as an object literal and for the sake of simplicity I'd like to do two things:

1. Have the object available globally
2. Use the object name (as globally defined) for all references (vs. using `this`)

So, I've run some tests, done research, and am not finding any good reason NOT to take this approach. My question is - am I missing something? Perf tests actually seem to favor my method and from a logistical level I don't see any issues. Looking at other frameworks I've seen a mix, but I know that the `this` reference is revered by many programmers.

For reference...

A very minimal example of my approach:

```
var myobj = {

    someVal: 'foo',

    init: function(){
       // Make myobj available globally
       window.myobj = myobj;
       // Fire off a method
       myobj.doStuff();
    },

    doStuff: function(){
        // Just print out the contents...
        console.log(myobj.someVal);
    }
}

myobj.init();
```

Note the references are all to the global, not `this`.

Like I said, I've seen a mix of this, I guess I just would like to know if this could cause issues in the long-run or if this a much ado about nothing.

Comment: Referencing globals is silly, try to avoid it. Usage of `this` is done for flexibility

Comment: I understand this provides flexibility, but for a framework where it's accessing the parent scope I feel like it provides consistency. I'm more concerned about actual perfromance issues.

Comment: actual performance issues on this are a stupid micro optimization, don't worry about it.

Comment: With what has the potential to become a large framework I just wanted to cover all bases re. performance.

Comment: "large framework" and performance don't go hand in hand.

Comment: A poorly performing framework would be a major issue. If I'm building something that loads heavy it could have a detrimental affect on uptake and usage. They may not go hand-in-hand but it should definitely be a consideration

Comment: I mean frameworks generally introduce so many layers of abstractions you can just forget about performance. If you want performance, don't write a framework, write many small modules that do one thing well and performantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as limitations go, the first thing that comes to mind is that you could only have one instance of this object.  Trying to initialize a new one would wipe out the object.

Another reason for using `this` rather than a global variable name is that `this` will point to the correct object even if the name of the variable changes.

If you really want this to be a "create once" global object whose name never changes then this technique isn't technically wrong.  But it won't be able to be used in any other situation.  It is probably wiser to consider writing code that will be more adaptable if the requirements change (for instance if you use a library that causes a naming conflict with the chosen variable name)

Using `this` lets you be flexible in renaming the variable and passing it in different contexts without worrying about tracking variable names.  It also will make it easy to change if naming conflicts arise.

Comment: Since it's an application framework I'm not concerned with naming conflicts. Also, as a framework for an app there will only be one instance. Good points though, definitely +1

Comment: Plus `this` will resolve methods faster than lookup from the very topmost scope.